# javascript regex to capture single quotes when not surrounding text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture double-single quotes when they do not encapsulate other text.

What I am aiming for is 'hello ''world''

I have tried using the ! not on the text but that won't work, how can I capture this ?

```
var str = "hello '' ''world''"

// > hello '' ''world'' 
console.log(str.replace( /''![a-z]{1,}''/g),'');

// > hello  world
console.log(str.replace( /''/g,''));

// desired output > hello ''world''
```

## EDIT

Sorrie, I was trying to create a simple example and have some answers that work for the original example, but I need to replace the '' with NULL instead of nothing i.e.

```
// desired output > hello NULL ''world''
```

Comment: It unclear what you're trying to do.  You show a sample string.  But, what is the desired result?

Comment: What I am aiming for is 'hello ''world''

Comment: is that single quote before hello should take part in result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character negation inside character classes (a.k.a. Negated character classes) are achieved using the `^` char.

So, in your case, replace the `!` with `^`. Try this:

```
var str = "hello '' ''world''"

// > hello NULL ''world'' 
console.log(str.replace( /''([^a-z]{1,}'')/g,"NULL$1"));
```

For a more complete example, maybe this would be better suited:

```
var str = "hello '' ''world'' ''hello'' '' world"

console.log(str.replace( /(^|[^a-z])''([^a-z]+|$)/g,"$1NULL$2"));
// > "hello NULL ''world'' ''hello'' NULL world"
```

Comment: Thanks, your example works, but I need to change my desired output as my original example was not accurate. Instead of replacing the '' with nothing, I need to replace it with NULL, I have updated my original question.

Comment: I have replaced the example. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, that works based on the revised example, but if I have multiple occurences of '' then it only replaces the first one i.e.: "hello '' ''world'' ''hello'' '' world"

Comment: Okay, that's expected. How would you describe the output for that particular example?

Comment: hello NULL ''world'' ''hello'' NULL world

Comment: Ok. I added another expression. Maybe that is closer? Let me know if those `''` at the beginning or end matter.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience, that produces [hello NULL ''worldNULL ''helloNULL '' world] instead of [hello NULL ''world'' ''hello'' NULL world]

Comment: No problem at all. I changed it a bit. Can you please look again?

Comment: that produces [hello NULL ''world'' ''hello'' NULL world]  :-) - which is correct, thank you sooo much

Comment: How could this be modified so that it will not just include [a-z] but any character i.e 'hello 1-2345 ????'

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
"hello '' ''world''".replace( /''\s*''/g,'\'\'');
//"hello ''world''"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried to create a simple example initially, your suggestion works based on my original question, but I need to replace the '' with NULL and not nothing